# Veracode showing CWE-611 Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference java fix for documentbuilder

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, security, veracode

Veracode static scan showing two flows as CWE 611 XXE vulnerability in the app. We are doing Java xml parsing using DocumentBuilderFactory as below.

```
`final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            final StringReader sr = new StringReader(this.responseXml);
            final InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
            // SAST Vulnerability fix 611 - Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference
            //factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);  //JRS - Causing an error at runtime
            //factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);  //JRS - Causing an error at runtime
            //factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);  //JRS - Causing an error at runtime
            
            final Document document = builder.parse(is);// new File(argv[0]) );

`
```

But when i include above commented code my test cases are failing.i am geting nullpoint exceptions so my test cases getting failed, as its not getting expected output.. Kindly suggest.

I have referred  https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html . but no effect still. if anyone has any suggestion.

Comment: You really like to keep us in suspense aren't you? What is the error you get?

Comment: i am geting nullpoint exceptions so my test cases getting failed, as its not getting expected output..

Comment: My question wasn't so much about a description as it was to your actual test case and exception stacktrace.